# Ordering MYSQL Results by 'MONTH' when month is stored as a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my database that stores the release month of many products, this is stored as a word 'January', 'March' etc...

I need to output the products in the order of month descending however the problem is that because the month is stored as a string my current query is ordering the products by month alphabetically.

Here is my current query

```
SELECT * FROM models ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC LIMIT 3
```

Is there possibly a way I can still sort these in descending month order, for example, December, November...

Comment: Why not store months as integers? That said, MySQL knows the names of the months so you can ask it to tap into its knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `field()`:

```
order by year desc,
         field(month, 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December') desc
```

Or, transform the value to date:

```
order by str_to_date(concat(year, '-', month), '%Y-%M')) desc
```